# intellij idea: defined environment variable not recognized in maven pom

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a java project opened in IntelliJ IDEA version 2018.1

I have defined an environment variable **MY_VAR** as **/some/path/here** in 
    File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner -> Environment Variables

In my pom.xml, in the properties secion, I have defined my property as

```
<myProperty>${env.MY_VAR}/morepath</myProperty>
```

However, IntelliJ IDEA complains that "Cannot resolve symbol 'env.MY_VAR'"

Comment: FWIW - I am seeing this exact same behavior.  Must be a bug in IntelliJ 2018.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible two workarounds:

Setting the variable from terminal:

```
set env MY_VAR /some/path/here
```

Then restart your IDE.

---

Another options is to add `export MY_VAR=/some/path/here` **~/.profile** file.
Then restart your computer.